# Customizing array objects with shared material

Tags: texturing, materials

I have an array of objects that share the same material. In addition to several other nodes, the material setup has a texture node hooked up to a mapping node. I would like to set the mapping rotation of the texture node independently for each object  in the array and keep everything else in the material the same. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. In object mode, select the objects that need to be unlinked. Press U, select Materials+Tex.